# How to use calculated results in a repetitive algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

This is what I want to accomplish:

1. let the user type in a number with four digits
2. if this number is not equal to 6174 (Kaprekar’s constant) then sort the numbers in two ways:
   a. from the biggest to the smallest number
   b. from the smallest to the biggest
3. Subtract the bigger number with the smaller
4. If the result is not equal to 6174, then do the calculation again and write the result for each and every calculation
5. When the result is equal to 6174, write a message to show that the calculation is done

This is what I’ve tried:

```
print("type in a number")
number = (input())
while number != 6174:
    start_big = "".join(sorted(number, reverse=True))
    start_small = "".join(sorted(number))
    number = (int(start_big)-int(start_small))
    print(number)
print("Calculation finnished!")
```

I’m getting the error:

```
start_big = "".join(sorted(number, reverse=True)) TypeError: 'int'
object is not iterable
```

Comment: "finished" only has one 'n'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate this:

```
number = (int(start_big)-int(start_small))
```

The type of `number` becomes `int`, so in the next iteration the error occurs.

One solution would be

```
print("type in a number")
number = input()
while number != "6174":
    start_big = "".join(sorted(number, reverse=True))
    start_small = "".join(sorted(number))
    number = str((int(start_big) - int(start_small)))
    print(number)
print("Calculation finnished!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  You need to convert `number` to an iterable.   I suggest:

```
    start_big = "".join(sorted(str(number), reverse=True))  
    start_small = "".join(sorted(str(number)number))
```

Comment: Sorry for the rubbish.  I hit post too soon by accident.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the input number to an iterable, you can just do

```
number = iter(number)
```

also you need to change the while loop condition:

```
while int(number) != 6174:
```

for printing the number just do this:

```
number = str((int(start_big)-int(start_small)))
```

Comment: `iter(324)` gives me an error.  I don't think that will work.

Comment: you cant provide int to iter as they do not have an index method, but strings do.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues with your solution:

1. `input()` always returns a string, so `number` will never be an integer and as such it will never be equal to `6174`. So your loop will still run for an input of `6174`.

   You need to convert the string into a number first, you can do that by simply calling `int()` on the string. Note that this may fail, so you might want to [ask the user for input until they enter a valid number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/216074).
2. Once `number` is an integer, it is no longer an iterable, so you cannot call `sorted()` on it. If you want to sort *the digits*, then you need to convert it into a string first: `sorted(str(number))`.

Comment: Point 1:  Once through the loop, `number` is an int, so the loop will only run once.

Comment: Why do I have to change the integers to strings when I'm sorting the numbers? I thought strings where only text but now I´m changing integers to strings to be able to use them in a calculation which means that the strings acts like numbers. I also wonder why integers can´t be used in the while-loop. Why is an integer not a iterable?

Comment: How do you *sort* a number like `6174`? It’s just one number, so there is nothing you can sort. What you want to do is sort the *digits* of the number. In order to get the digits of the number, you can convert it to a string `'6174'` and then you can iterate over every character of that string (`'6'`, `'1'`, `'7'`, `'4'`). An integer can be used in the condition of a while loop but your initial value of `number` is not an integer but a string (since it comes from `input()`).

Comment: I get it! Thanks a lot! :)